# How to extract tables from a PDF into a usable tibble using R

Tags: r, pdf, text-mining

I'm trying to extract tables from a `.pdf` file using R.  I've tried using the `tabulizer` package which extracts the tables into a large list.  I would like to take it two steps further by cleaning up the tables (which are all different) and put them into a `tibble` (or `data.frame`).

```
#incase you don't have the tabulizer package, the below is needed
install.packages("rJava")
library(rJava) # load and attach 'rJava' now
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("ropensci/tabulizer", args="--no-multiarch")
library(tabulizer)

#set path to file
file <- "https://www.sdccu.com/CURates/HomeLoanRates.pdf"

#extract tables
mortgagerates <- extract_tables(file, encoding = "UTF-8")

#first table from the third page
mortgagerates[[7]]
```

This is the output from the last line of code:

```
> mortgagerates[[7]]
  [,1]                                                                                                                  
 [1,] "ADJUSTABLE RATE MORTGAGES: JUMBO LOANS $453,101 TO $1,500,000 
(Purchase or Refinance)"                               
 [2,] "Available for all counties:"                                                                                         
 [3,] " Purchases or refinances up to 95% LTV with a maximum loan amount of 
$679,650.  Cash-out refinances up to 70% LTV."
 [4,] ""                                                                                                                    
 [5,] " Purchases or refinances up to 80% LTV with a maximum loan amount of 
$1,500,000."                                   
 [6,] "Annual Percentage Loans Amortized Over 30 Years. Rate Rate (APR) 
Points Per $1,000 Borrowed Estimated Payment"       
 [7,] "5/1 CMT 3.500% 4.394% 0.000 $4.49"                                                                                   
 [8,] "7/1 CMT 3.750% 4.358% 0.000 $4.63"                                                                                   
 [9,] "3.500% 4.322% 1.000 $4.49"
```

What's the best way to wrangle this into a tibble similar to what is on the actual pdf doc? Image of exactly what I want out of the table below:

[image]

The below is the update from `dput(mortgagerates[7])`

```
> file
  [,1]                                                                                                                  
 [1,] "ADJUSTABLE RATE MORTGAGES: JUMBO LOANS $453,101 TO $1,500,000 
(Purchase or Refinance)"                               
 [2,] "Available for all counties:"                                                                                         
 [3,] " Purchases or refinances up to 95% LTV with a maximum loan amount of 
 $679,650.  Cash-out refinances up to 70% LTV."
 [4,] ""                                                                                                                    
 [5,] " Purchases or refinances up to 80% LTV with a maximum loan amount of 
 $1,500,000."                                   
 [6,] "Annual Percentage Loans Amortized Over 30 Years. Rate Rate (APR) 
Points 
Per $1,000 Borrowed Estimated Payment"       
 [7,] "5/1 CMT 3.500% 4.394% 0.000 $4.49"                                                                                   
 [8,] "7/1 CMT 3.750% 4.358% 0.000 $4.63"                                                                                   
 [9,] "3.500% 4.322% 1.000 $4.49"
```

Comment: Could you `dput(mortgagerates[[7]]])`?

Comment: Thanks @csgroen.  dput gets me another step closer.  I would just need to figure out how to parse the column names that already have spaces in between each word.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clean. Can you post the results of that? This way we'll have a reproducible example of your column to tweak in R.

Comment: added @csgroen.

Comment: have you read [this tutorial](https://ropensci.org/tutorials/tabulizer_tutorial/)? and tried `extract_tables(file, pages = 3, method = "data.frame")` or extract_area?

Comment: Hi @phiver.  I did and it gave the same ouput as `dput`

Comment: @Jordan don't put the dput result in `file`. Just `dput(mortgagerates[[7]]])` in the console and copy the result.

Comment: I did. The result is the edited part of the question above.

Answer (score 1):

The layout of tables in this file is too complex for them to be extracted automatically without more input. The way to address it with `tabulizer` is to supply areas that contain tables. For this particular table you can do something like:

```
file <- "https://www.sdccu.com/CURates/HomeLoanRates.pdf"
area <- locate_areas(file, pages = 3)
area
[[1]]
      top      left    bottom     right 
442.20975  30.50972 549.83752 592.01857
mortgagerates <- extract_tables(file, pages = 3, area = area, guess = FALSE)
```

This gives:

```
 > as.data.frame(mortgagerates[[1]])
                                                     V1         V2 V3     V4                                    V5
1 Annual Percentage Loans Amortized Over 30 Years. Rate Rate (APR)    Points Estimated Payment Per $1,000 Borrowed
2                                        5/1 CMT 3.625%     4.439%     0.000                                 $4.56
3                                        7/1 CMT 3.875%     4.417%     0.000                                 $4.70
4                                                3.625%     4.381%     1.000                                 $4.56
```